# Java regex pattern for double curly braces

Tags: java, regex

I have a

```
String url = "/rest/devices/{{deviceId}}";
```

in which `{{deviceId}}` value i want to replace with some deviceId.

```
url.replace("{{deviceId}}", device.getId());
```

But it's not working.

Therefore, **What to do?**

Comment: Have you tried escaping the braces (e.g. `"\\{\\{deviceId\\}\\}"`)?

Comment: @anij, please explain what you mean with _"it's not working"_.

Comment: @KennethK. `String.replace` is NOT regex-based, so no need to escape.

Comment: @Alex when I'm using `.replace()` its not replacing the value, and while using `replaceAll()`, then getting the following exception.
`java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{{deviceId}}`

Comment: please see the answer by @maszter, it's very likely that this is the reason. The method call itself is correct, but the method **does not modify the original string** — it returns a copy of the string with the replacement done. You may be just discarding the return value, thus the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are missing an assignment and result of

`url.replace("{{deviceId}}", device.getId());` is ignored.

What about:

`url = url.replace("{{deviceId}}", device.getId());`

Comment: You should explain why the OP's code does not work